# Can stack overflow through recursion cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: recursion, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

Can a recursive call in a function lead to a segmentation fault if the memory stack use is high?

Comment: yes, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739589/why-segmentation-fault-error-in-recursive-function/59751808#59751808 where it just happened, even with small calls

Answer (score 0):

> Can a recursive call in a function lead to a segmentation fault if the memory stack use is high?

Yes: this happens *all the time* if you try to execute on a small stack, if you use [too much](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23184984/50617), or if you have [infinite recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739589/why-segmentation-fault-error-in-recursive-function/59751808#59751808).

Comment: Yes, infinite recursion is my friend these days.